# Anybody Implemented pagination using SLDS

Tags: slds

I have to implement pagination by using SLDS. I didn't able find any example of pagination. Please provide example?

Comment: Do you only mean the look and feel of pagination numbers at the footer? Basically slds only affects look and feel

Answer (score 3):

SLDS does not explicitly define pagination, as of version 2.1.4, but there is an [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/creating-simple-real-estate-app-lightning-components.html) on the Developer Blog. As far as I can tell, though, it is not explicitly defined as an officially encouraged design pattern. Most of the time, Lightning Experience simply uses infinite scrolling instead of pagination controls.

Comment: is that true for mobile layout as well ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna From my limited experience, yes, mobile pages also prefer inifinite scrolling.